# convert USB to RCA phone plug in order to close a switch

Tags: usb, switches, serial, rca

I would like to know if it is possible to convert a USB signal to a RCA phone plug signal in order to close a switch contact.  There are pushbutton switches that can remotely close a switch by means of a cable with a standard 3.5 mm plug on the end.  These are attached to specialized switch boxes for adaptive devices for people with disabilities.  Instead of having a physical pushbutton as the component sending the signal to the switch box, I would like to have the signal originate from a software program and be conveyed through USB or RS-232 and then be converted to the appropriate signal for closing a switch.  This is a specialized need and I am not an engineer, so it's kind of hard to explain what I am needing.  I do not really know how to look for such a solution.  I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

There are devices available such as [this one](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/k8055-usb-experiment-interface-board-n67bh) (also available ready-built) that will do what you want. That might be bigger and more cumbersome than what you're looking for, however.

In reply to comment: Not much simpler, for USB, although you may find something smaller, with fewer channels - just search for 'USB Relay'. This looks the most promising route.

An alternative approach, if you do want something simpler, <strike>then you may have to step outside of Windows</strike> - you don't say anything more specific than 'software' but I'm assuming you mean Windows or anyway a modern OS - but in the days of DOS, you had more direct access to the hardware, so could for instance use one of the RS232 control signals (DTR etc) plus a diode and a small relay. <strike>But AFAIK this isn't available under Windows.</strike> In fact - ref comments - this is still available under Windows too.

Comment: That might work for me, but is there anything simpler than that?

Comment: The modem control signals (if implemented by the hardware) are still available under windows and other modern operating systems.

Comment: @Chris Stratton Interesting - my understanding is that you can enable and disable them ie select how handshaking is performed, but not actually control their state from code. Could you expand on that?

Comment: No, you can control them from code.

Comment: @Chris Stratton Yes, I stand corrected. Didn't check that thoroughly enough last night - now I've found the EscapeCommFunction, which does exactly what's reqd. Thanks - useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is to use an FTDI chip, such as the [FT232R](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf), which connects via USB to a virtual COM port, and on the other side of the IC presents a full set of RS-232 leads, at TTL levels, including TX/RX, DTR, RTS, CTS and DSR. It is available in a [28-pin SSOP package](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/FT232RL-REEL/768-1007-1-ND/1836402) for $4.50 in single quantities.

You can then use the DTR lead to control a transistor or MOSFET to drive your relay.  There are literally dozens of answers here describing how to do that so I won't repeat it here.   The DTR lead can be easily manipulated using Windows software (we're doing it right now in one of our test boards to reset a processor using C#.)

Comment: Yes, though there's little need to build this with a bare chip for a one-off, since a typical consumer USB serial adapter (ultimately built around such a part) will work.  As that will include a line driver on the control signals as well as the data their signal will be inverted and may have a higher level, but that is not really a problem for designing a relay driver.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I mostly included this because PeterG said it couldn't be done under Windows, while I am using this solution every day (and it's cheaper than buying a complete board).  I see you also added a comment under his post re controlling modem lines under Windows.

Comment: @tcrosley - whoa - I didn't (intend to) say that it couldn't be done via extra hardware - I'm talking about the built-in serial port here. To the best of my knowledge Windows doesn't allow direct control of DTR etc on that - but Chris (or you) might put me right on that too!

Comment: @tcrosley . . . yeah, Chris *did* put me right!

Comment: @peterG If you have an actual COM port on your PC (most don't anymore, I insisted on one when I got my last computer), then this becomes very simple.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to approach the problem. The two I'd suggest you looking into first are [phidgets](http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?product_id=1014), which should have a solution for you.

Another choice is an arduino with a [relay shield](http://shieldlist.org/seeedstudio/relay).

There are certainly cheaper and more elegant ways to tackle this, but from the tone of your question I'm guessing you need something that is easy to use and has a large community to support questions you have as you progress. You'll find both in the above two options.